# Как на стороне web-службы принять данные, посланные ей с использованием метода WebRequest.POST?

Tags: c#, post

Мне нужно запрограммировать приём данных, отправленных с помощью метода WebRequest.POST. Для отправки данных (например строки в XML-формате) использую следующий код (где this.XMLReport.InnerXml это как раз строка, которую я посылаю):

```
private void PostXMLDocument()
{
    // Создать экземпляр WebRequest с uri ресурса, который принимает данные
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://webservice.com/xmlreport/");
    // Включить проверку подлинности
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    // Для отправки данных используется метод POST
    request.Method = "POST";
    // Подготовить данные для отправки.
    string postData = this.XMLReport.InnerXml;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Установить тип передаваемого контента.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Установить длину передаваемого контента.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Получает поток, содержащий данные запроса.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Записать данные в этот поток.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Закрыйть поток.
    dataStream.Close();
}
```

Как на принимающей стороне нужно "ловить" эту передачу? Предположим, что метод веб-службы, осуществляющий приём посланных данных, поддерживает протокол HTTP-POST. Мне нужно просто принять строку, которая была послана методом Webrequest.POST и записать её в буфер. Вот с помощью какого API на стороне веб-службы осуществляется "получение" посылки, высланной посредством WebRequest.POST?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - [ASP.NET WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) с примерно таким контроллером:

```
public XmlReportController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }
}
```

Попробуйте создать стандартный проект - в нем будет шаблон ValuesController c заглушками для GET/POST/DELETE. Возьмите его за основу.